# Maximum Execution time of 30 second exceeded | PHP

Tags: php

When I click on the link in the dashboard, I recieved this error
Can anyone please help related to this.

[Please Check the Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OYRc.png)

I think this is the issue of the maximum execution time and may be some extension missing.
Could it be the problem of mbstring extension?